# deflection of mild steel hollow tube beam

Tags: mechanical-engineering, beam, deflection

I am trying to compute the deflection of a hollow tube of mild steel, and my computation seems to give radically different results than a couple of online calculators.  Apparently one is in error.

The tube is 1.5" nominal Schedule 40, 100" long, with a point load of 100lb at the center.   The formula for maximum deflection of a simple supported beam with point load at center is P*L^/48EI.  For mild steel, E = 2.9e7.   The tube has 1.9" OD and 1.61" ID, which gives its area moment of inertia as 0.310 in^4.   Thus the maximum deflection is 0.23".

However, both these calculators:

https://www.easycalculation.com/engineering/mechanical/deflection-round-tube-beams.php

https://www.meracalculator.com/engineering/deflection-round-tube-beams.php

give similar and much higher results of about 3.5".   They appear to be using a factor of 3, instead of 48, in the denominator in the formula.   This is correct for a cantilever beam with a point load at the end.   But neither site suggests it's for a cantilever beam, making me wonder if there's something special about round tube beams that I do not understand.

Comment: Does either website indicate how the beam is constrained or loaded? Without those details, the website is useless.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Gonna be a vertical pipe.   And 100 inches, not 100 feet.

Comment: @JohnHoltz Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct. The deflection formula was noted below the first cal page. The second should be similar.

[image]

Similarly, below  the second calculator:

**Formula**

MI for Solid Round Beams = (pi * (OD^4 - ID^4))/64

**Deflection = (length^3 * force)/(3 * E * MI)**

Bending Stress = (force * length) * (0.5 * height)/MI

Comment: So they meant it to be for a cantilevered beam, even though they didn't say so ?   Lame.     But 3.5" deflection seem pretty obviously wrong, just intuitively.

Comment: Any calculator should list the formula, units, and explanation all of the parameters in the formula, otherwise, switch to other calculators that are well documented.

Comment: I actually prefer my own calculator.   A little spreadsheet with three sets of entries.  One set is modulus of elasticity of various materials, one set is the moment of inertia of various cross-sections, and one is 4 cases (point and distributed loads for simple-supported and cantilevered).   In each set, I check one entry.  And I enter the length of the beam, and the load.  Works for almost everything I do around the house and shop.   But I like to check it against another calculator from time to time, and was disturbed when I got an order of magnitude larger deflection.

Comment: Yes, it is a wise choice.

Comment: Odd that the formula you quote above (which I've seen a few places too) calls it a "SOLID round beam".   But it's a tube, ID and OD.

Comment: Good note. I guess they mean the pipe wall is solid rather than perforated.

Comment: "Solid" round beam means you aren't calculating thin-wall buckling.